# How to show elements from 2 tables ( existing in one , another or both)

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables than i  need to fuse together for data analysis.

Table One ( shows year consumption of items with values, from a contract)
Table One fields : product code, quantity, total value, contract number

Table Two (shows contract defined included products)
Table Two fields : included product code, included quantity, total included value, contract number

I need to join both of them so that shows per contract, all the related products, both consumed or included, so that shows either i only have consumed but not included, included but not consumed and included and consumed...

Something like this :

Contract|Product Code|Consumed qty|Included Qty|Consumed Total|Included Total
CTC001|X0001|55|45|550|450

CTC001|X0002|20|NULL|200|NULL

CTC001|X0003|NULL|10|NULL|100

CTC002|X0001|10|10|100|100

Using inner join only shows the ones on both tables
Using left or right joins shows all from one table and similar and null's from other table...
My goal was to show from both tables, has the example

Any help or tip ?

(this is my current query, field names not all equal as example, but you get the idea :

```
SELECT        dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr.strCodArtigo, dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos.strCodArtigo AS Expr2, dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos.QTDTOTAL, 
                         dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr.fltQuantLimiteInc, dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos.VALORTOTAL, dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr.Total, dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos.strCodSecContrato, 
                         dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos.strCodTpContrato, dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos.strCodExercContrato, dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos.intNumeroContrato, dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr.strCodSeccao, 
                         dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr.strCodTpContrato AS Expr1, dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr.strCodExercicio, dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr.intNumero
FROM            dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr INNER JOIN
                         dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos ON dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr.strCodSeccao = dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos.strCodSecContrato AND 
                         dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr.strCodTpContrato = dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos.strCodTpContrato AND 
                         dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr.strCodExercicio = dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos.strCodExercContrato AND dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr.intNumero = dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos.intNumeroContrato AND 
                         dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr.strCodArtigo = dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos.strCodArtigo
```

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS that you're using and sample data from both tables that you use for your expected results.  Is Consumed Quantity and Consumed Total the columns that are in Table One?  You can use FULL OUTER JOIN, or maybe a WHERE clause on your LEFT join.

Comment: Using SQL SERVER.

Comment: Table1 Data Example (fields : Contract, product, consumedqty,consumedvalue)
CTC001|X0001|55|550,
CTC001|X0002|20|200,
CTC002|X0001|10|100

Comment: Table2 Data Example (fields : Contract, product, contractedqty,contractedvalue)
CTC001|X0001|45|450,
CTC001|X0003|10|100,
CTC002|X0001|10|100

Comment: Please learn to use table alias.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a `full join`:

```
SELECT aic.strCodArtigo, tc.strCodArtigo AS Expr2, tc.QTDTOTAL, 
       aic.fltQuantLimiteInc, tc.VALORTOTAL, aic.Total, tc.strCodSecContrato, 
       tc.strCodTpContrato, tc.strCodExercContrato, tc.intNumeroContrato, aic.strCodSeccao, 
       aic.strCodTpContrato AS Expr1, aic.strCodExercicio, aic.intNumero
FROM dbo.USR_View_ArtIncludContr aic FULL JOIN
     dbo.USR_View_TotaisConsumos tc
     ON aic.strCodSeccao = tc.strCodSecContrato AND 
        aic.strCodTpContrato = tc.strCodTpContrato AND 
        aic.strCodExercicio = tc.strCodExercContrato AND 
        aic.intNumero = tc.intNumeroContrato AND 
        aic.strCodArtigo = tc.strCodArtigo
```

Notice that column aliases make the query much easier to write and to read.

Comment: You used an INNER JOIN :)

Comment: I had reached that result before, my problem is the way i want to show my data... Since i have contract number ( ON aic.strCodSeccao = tc.strCodSecContrato AND 
        aic.strCodTpContrato = tc.strCodTpContrato AND 
        aic.strCodExercicio = tc.strCodExercContrato AND 
        aic.intNumero = tc.intNumeroContrato ) And product code  (aic.strCodArtigo = tc.strCodArtigo) on both tables, my goal is to show only one column, like the example i made... the way you sugested, which is great and i appreciate, shows my contract and product code from both tables in separated columns

Answer (score 0):

Just figure out an workaround...

i could use CASE WHEN for the contract and for product code...

Something like this in select :

"CASE WHEN AIC.strCodArtigo IS NULL THEN TC.strCodArtigo WHEN TC.strCodArtigo IS NULL THEN AIC.strCodArtigo ELSE AIC.strCodArtigo END AS ARTIGO "

And use FULL OUTER JOIN

In case anyone has a better way, i appreciate any opinion